# Drawing JFrame's GlassPane over JApplet

Tags: java, swing, awt

I've been trying to draw sort of an 'overlay' on top of a JApplet for debugging, but come to find out; it doesn't want to.

**Although!** If I change the *JApplet* to a *JPanel*, then it works perfectly fine.

I can't find any logical reasoning behind this rather than that JApplet itself extends Applet which is an AWT component, and JPanel extends JComponent which is the root swing component. (As far as I'm concerned)

An animated image of what's going on: http://puu.sh/5NUV2/7aa1c26671.gif

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class OverlayTest extends JFrame {

    public static final Color OVERLAY_COLOR = new Color( 200, 10, 10, 127 );

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new OverlayTest();
    }

    public JPanel overlay;
    public Component applet;

    public OverlayTest() {
        this.setTitle( "" );
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        this.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        this.setResizable( false );

        this.applet = new JApplet() {
            {
                this.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
                this.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 256, 256 ) );
            }

            @Override
            public void paint( Graphics g ) {
                g.setColor( this.getBackground() );
                g.fillRect( 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight() );

                g.setColor( Color.ORANGE );
                g.drawRect( 16, 16, this.getWidth() - 32, this.getHeight() - 32 );

                System.out.println( "Painted applet" );
            }
        };

        this.overlay = new JPanel( null ) {
            {
                this.setOpaque( false );
                OverlayTest.this.setGlassPane( this );
                this.setVisible( true );
            }

            @Override
            public void paint( Graphics g ) {
                g.setColor( OVERLAY_COLOR );
                g.fillOval( 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight() );

                System.out.println( "Painted overlay" );
            }
        };

        this.add( this.applet, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Custom painting is normally done within the `paintComponent` method, failing to honour the paint chaing (by not calling `super.paintXxx`) will cause any number of issues

Comment: Remember that `JApplet` is heavy weight component (of sorts), and it may be an issue with the z-ordering issues of mixing heavy and light weight components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of possible issues...

1. `JApplet` is conceptual very similar to a `JFrame`, it has a `JRootPane` which contains the content and other elements
2. It could be related to z-order issues with mixing AWT and Swing components
3. Breaking the paint chain won't help either...

Instead of trying to set the frame's glass pane, why not set the applets?

Comment: I forgot to include that I have already tried to set the applets, but the way the applet redraws is in parts. So if I draw a transparent rectangle over it then it will continue to fill the parts that haven't been redrawn, until they appear like they're an opaque rectangle of the color I drew.

Comment: This is because you've overriden `paint` of the applet, which is doing two things 1- Because you've not called `super.paint`, it's not painting any of the content of the applet (ie, the `JRootPane`, `contentPane`, `GlassPane`, `JLayeredPane` or `JMenuBar`), but even if you did (call `super.paint`); 2- You've painted directly over everything anyway

Comment: I don't need any of the other content of the applet drawn. I'm simply trying to draw a glass pane over it without making it the applets glass pane.

Comment: The problem is, you do.  In order to an applet to render the glass pane, you need to allow the applet to honour it's paint chain. I don't think it's going to be possible to add an applet to a frame and use the frame's glass pane due to AWT z-order issues

Comment: Well thanks for your time and efforts. I love you MadProgrammer.